# class constructor creating instance of arbitrary struct C++

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

I want to make a class that creates an instance of an arbitrary struct and then has methods to write and load these structs from a file system.  I currently do this with a macro that takes the name of the instance of the struct and saves and loads it.  I wanted to instead create a class object that would wrap all of these together, but I don't know how to pass and use an arbitrary struct to the constructor.

I am limited to C++11.
The code would work something like this

```
struct typeA{
   int age;
   int weight;
};

struct typeB{
    char name[10];
    int height;
};

class StructControl{
    public:
    void target;
    StructControl(void ITEM){
        ITEM target;
    }
    void S(void * addr,uint32_t size){
     //code for saving
    }
    void L(void * addr, unint32_t size){
     //code for loading
    }
    void Save(){
       S(&target,sizeof(target));
    }
    void Load(){
       L(&target,sizeof(target));
    }
};

void main(){
   StructControl myA(typeA);
   myA.target.age=45;
   myA.Save();
   StructControl myB(typeB);
   myB.height=110;
   myB.Save();
}
```

Comment: *but I don't know how to pass and use an arbitrary struct to the constructor.* -- Templates and static polymorphism?  Or a class with virtual functions where you override the `Save()` function in the derived classes?

Comment: To do exactly what's asked, you should look into templates. But I'm guessing your saving and loading code is just treating the structs like simple arrays of bytes in memory. So beware that if you ever give it a struct with anything other than a primitive `int`, `char`, etc then this exact design isn't going to be sufficient to work.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers and warnings.  c++ is far from my bread and butter and I know that there is a ton I don't know.  I'll go take a look at templates and see if I can figure out how to put them to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to the @TheUndeadFish and @PaulMcKenzie for pointing me towards templates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;


struct typeA{
   int age=25;
   int weight=13;
};

struct typeB{
    char name[10];
    int height=55;
};

template <class TYPE>
class StructControl{
    public:
    TYPE target;
    char selfname[10];
    StructControl(const char * name){
        strcpy(selfname,name);
        printf("name:%s\n",selfname);

    }
    void Save(){
      printf("Saving object of size %lu to  addr:%p\n",sizeof(target),&target);
      //also save the struct to file
    }
    void Load(){
     printf("Loading object of size %lu to addr:%p\n",sizeof(target),&target);
      //also load the struct from file
    }
};
};

int main(){
   StructControl<typeA> myA("myA");
   printf("myA Age:%d\n",myA.target.age);
   myA.target.age=45;
   printf("myA Age:%d\n",myA.target.age);
   myA.Save();
   myA.Load();
   StructControl<typeB> myB("myB");
   printf("myB Height:%d\n",myB.target.height);
   myB.target.height=110;
   printf("myB Height:%d\n",myB.target.height);
   myB.Save();
   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
name:myA
myA Age:25
myA Age:45
Saving object of size 8 to  addr:0x7fffbfb716b0
Loading object of size 8 to addr:0x7fffbfb716b0
name:myB
myB Height:55
myB Height:110
Saving object of size 16 to  addr:0x7fffbfb716d0
```

Comment: `void S(void * addr,uint32_t size)` -- You don't need (or want) this to be a `void*`.  This would have been sufficient: `void S(TYPE* addr,uint32_t size)` -- the same thing with the other functions.  Using templates, you don't need `void *` (at least in this case).

Comment: that's a good point.  using `void` was carried over from when I was doing this with macros.  I also realized I didn't need the extra `S()` and `L()` functions.